# How to get mac startup time statistics？

Tags: macos, launchd

My mac startup process is a bit slow, how do I know what service is slowing down the startup?

I tried using launchctl and reading system.log, but these don't directly answer the question

Comment: Are you using the console app to read the system log? The database that holds these detailed timing is better than looking at a file on the filesystem. Not sure what you tried with launchctl….

Comment: Also, which part is slow (boot to login screen, login screen to Finder showing or Finder showing til user)? What makes you think a launchd manages background process is the culprit?

Comment: What model of mac? Could it be a hard drive (or full SSD) problem? Is it faster in SafeBoot, or booting to an external volume with a clean OS install? Have you run a utility like Etrecheck to see what Launch Agents and processes are installed?

Comment: @nohillside login screen to Finder.

Comment: @bmike How to get database files related to startup time?

Comment: @Karl  "Login screen to Finder" means the user processes are the likely cause. Check the speed of a brand new user account. Remove all Login Items, Launch Agents, and restore each one, then test login time.